# Meteor : Blink data when updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, jquery-animate, css-animations

I hope someone can help with this because it's quite frustrating.

I have examined all animation packages around, but they all seem to be activated by user action, for example clicking an item. What if the change is triggered from the server?

I want to display an animation when my Collection is changed from non-Meteor source. I have a Java demo app that can call a Meteor server method, which in turn updates the Collection.

The changes are displayed in the client so I know the basics are working, but how shall I code the client so that it for examples blink when changed?

Think "Stock market app".

A simple example that blinks an item in red when updated would be great. Also, how do I detect when items are inserted and deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a template for a list of favorite stocks, and a template for each stock:

```
<template name="favorites">
    {{#each favorites}}
      {{> stock}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="stock">
    <div class="row" id="{{_id}}">
        <div class="col-xs-6 symbol">{{symbol}}</span>
        <div class="col-xs-6 quote">{{quote}}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the `onRendered` template event you can create an observer to watch for changes to a specific query. Just use the same query you use to generate the favorites list. When a change occurs for any record, find it using jQuery and animate the highlight effect:

```
Template.favorites.onRendered(function() {
  var query = Favorites.find({}, { sort: { symbol: 1 } });

  var handle = query.observeChanges({
    changed: function (id, fields) {
      //this will highlight the row of the updated favorite, using the id from the Favorites collection
      $('#' + id).effect('highlight', {}, 1500);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I came up with a similar solution using Tracker.autorun() instead of onRendered(). And observe() instead if observeChanges(). But I'm confident now that I know the proper way of solving this kind of problem in Meteor.

Comment: This part:  <div class="row" id="{{_id}}">  together with $('#' + id).effect('highlight', {}, 1500); was also clever!